# Calling functions based on command received in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-pattern

Given a text command, I need to figure out which class and method in the project needs to be called.
e.g. `/help` should trigger `Generic.new.help` and an `/edit` should trigger the `user.edit` function respectively.

What I've done is this huge switch-case tree which does the work. Looks somewhat like,

```
case command
when '/help'
  Generic.new.help
when '/edit'
  user.edit
when /^\/action_[a-z]+$/
  user.action(command)
end
```

This works but was wondering if there is a better solution for the same.

The only additional problem in this whole scenario is the regex based commands for example, if the command is `/action_a` or `/action_b` it should invoke the same `user.action` method

Answer (score 1):

Calling different methods on some `user` object may be done as

```rb
user_methods = %w(show edit create update)
case
when user_methods.include?(command[1..-1])
  user.send(command[1..-1])
end
```

First line forms array of valid `user` methods as strings. `command[1..-1]` expression removes the first character (`/`) from `command`. If `command` exists in the array, `users`'s method `send` invokes command on this object.

As for regex you can

```rb
case command
when /^\/someaction_[a-z]+$/, /^\/anotheraction_[a-z]+$/
  real_cmd = command.split('_').first
  user.send(real_cmd[1..-1], command)
end
```

Splitting your command by underscore symbol gives you the real action name and you can `send` it as above.

Comment: This should work, I was wondering if there is a completely different way to do this.
But thank you